# Which path is given by Dijkstra?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, greedy

I am starting to learn algorithms and i am stuck with this simple directed graph example below:

Let's say A goes to B with a weighted edge of 3. Then A goes to C with weight 4. Finally B goes to D with 3 and C goes to D with 1.

Shortest obvious path from A to D is A, C, D.

Now i am sure i am doing something wrong with Dijkstra because i find A, B, D which is not true.

I first label A with 0 and all other vertices with infinity. Then from A, i relax B and C. From there, the lowest node is B and from B there is one adjacent non visited node which is D. So shortest path is A, B, D.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You also had a node C which was relaxed before .

If you now relax the C-D edge , you will get the shortest path A-C-D .
You seem to miss this case

Comment: But Dijkstra is greedy. So instead of going to C, i go to B because it lighter than C. Or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes , you will indeed go to B first . But you can't just stop if you have reached the destination . You need to take care of all the edges that belong to the nodes that have been relaxed

Comment: I suggest you go through the algorithm once again and it would be clear to you

Comment: Ok i understand now. So i check all the relaxed nodes and choose the path with min weight?

Comment: yes , precisely !

Comment: It was obvious thank you for your help.